# Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined in angular 2 assistance please

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas

I have browsed a number of solutions for this and none of them seem to work. And it even gets weirder. I decided to make a new angular 2 project, and drop the code in, and it works just fine. But in my project i keep getting the error in the title. Here is my code:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'MouseClick',
  templateUrl: './mouseClick.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mouseClick.scss']
})

export class MouseClick implements AfterViewInit {

@ViewChild('canvasTest') canvasTest: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {

  console.log('native element', this.canvasTest.nativeElement);
};
```

this returns with an error: 'Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined'.

The original code (not the console.log) inside was:

```
let ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D = this.canvasTest.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
```

The code above was throwing the error. So how can this be fixed?

canvasTest is defined as:

```
<canvas #canvasTest class="canvas-foreground" style="width:100%;height:715px;" tabindex="1"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can we see the template code where `#canvasTest` is defined?

Comment: Is the canvas element inside an `ngIf` conditonal container or inside an `ng-template`? If so, can we see that context?

Comment: I am not getting any error. Code works fine

Comment: No, it is not in an ngIf, nor in an ng-template. It is in an html page. simple div container with canvas inside it.

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem in a stackblitz. You could also provide the complete HTML markup of the template, just in case we would see something special.

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5wjisz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts it works fine